# Spring MVC 4 configuration and the 404 page

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new to spring MVC 4 and I have a problem- Each time I start a new project there is something wrong with the configuration which results in a 404 when I try to work with my controllers.

I there a way to see some logs which will make things more clear as to what I did wrong? I work with tomcat and I looked into his "logs" folder and there was nothing there...

Comment: Just check the `InternalViewResolver` is configured correctly or not. Try to provide the code so that we can provide correct resolution.

Comment: What logging framework do you use? Spring uses [JCL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging) so you need to plumb in some logging backend - for example [Log4j](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/). Then simply turn the logging level up to TRACE and Spring will spit out absolutely everything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use remote debugging from your Eclipse IDE, or debug the application from within the IDE. then you can debug the code line by line and see what is going wrong.

For Spring application development Spring Tool Suit has more support for developing Spring Applications.

EDIT:

You can also configure your Log level in Tomcat Environment. See this article for more information to change your configuration of logging accordingly (Run on DEBUG mode)

Comment: I would start by setting up logging correctly rather than plunging straight into the code with a debugger. Correctly configured logging will very quickly highlight configuration problems. A debugger is not overly helpful for diagnosing framework configuration issues.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yeah you are correct. I'm too spoiled with IDEs :P